# Too many Post were made to semaphore

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++

Hi have developped an sample code to implement.Multiple producer and single consumer problem.

I have taken a Queue and I have restricted the size of the to 20.So I am using semaphore  and CrticalSection (windows api)to protect it.If more than 20 thread the queue it wont be allowed.that semaphore should protect it.

I have two method AdddTail(add msg in queue) and Remove Head (remove msg from the queue)method to manipulate the queue.

I am getting Error **Too many Post were made to semaphore**.I dont understand the problem.
I have 20 Producer thread with 8000 ms waiting and one consumer thread with 4000 ms wating.
I think ReleaseSemaphore is Causing the Problem.

```
BOOL CEventQueue::AddTail(LPVOID p)
{ 

       BOOL result;
       char* pMsg = (char*)p;
       char* pMsg1 = new char[100];
       int nOffset = strlen(pMsg);

       strcpy(pMsg1,pMsg);
       strcat(pMsg1," Waiting");
       PostMessage(hWnd,UWM_ONUPDATEPRODUCERLIST,(WPARAM)pMsg1,0);
       DWORD dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(handles,INFINITE);
       switch(WAIT_OBJECT_0)
       {
       case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
           {
           ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_QueueLock);
           queue.AddTail(p);
            ::LeaveCriticalSection(&m_QueueLock);
           result = ::ReleaseSemaphore(handles[SemaphoreIndex],1, NULL);
           }
           break;
       case WAIT_TIMEOUT:   
           return 0;
           break;
       }      
       if(!result)
       { /* failed */
           // caller can use ::GetLastError to determine what went wrong
           queue.RemoveTail();
          ErrorExit(_T("AddTail"));
       } /* failed */

       return result;
} // AddTail

 LPVOID result;

       switch(::WaitForMultipleObjects(2, handles, FALSE, INFINITE))
       {
            /* decode */
            case StopperIndex:   // shut down thread
              ::ExitThread(0);  // kill thread
              return NULL;      // return keeps C compiler happy

            case SemaphoreIndex: // semaphore
              ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_QueueLock);
              result = queue.RemoveHead();
              ::LeaveCriticalSection(&m_QueueLock);
              return result;

            case WAIT_TIMEOUT: // not implemented
            default:
            ASSERT(FALSE); // impossible condition
            return NULL;
            //::ReleaseSemaphore(handles[SemaphoreIndex],1, NULL);
      } /* decode */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `WaitForSingleObject(handles,INFINITE)` to `WaitForSingleObject(handles[SemaphoreIndex],INFINITE)`.

Change `switch(WAIT_OBJECT_0)` to `switch(dwWaitResult)` and add error handling to this switch.

`case StopperIndex:` should be case `StopperIndex + WAIT_OBJECT_0:`, apply same change to `case SemaphoreIndex:`

Turn you compilers warning level to max, and fix what it warns about.

The correct order of operations is:

Producer: lock the critical section, add to queue, release critical section, release semaphore.

Consumer: wait for semaphore, lock critical section, fetch from queue, release critical section.

Your code appears to wait for the semaphore in both producer and consumer, which'll deadlock.

Comment: I changed it as mentioned but now all thread is blocked at WaitForSingleObject(handles[SemaphoreIndex],INFINITE).they never move beyond that